# How close are you to an Epic / Legendary badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, daily-reputation-badges

Here's how to find out (or [see Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32087/how-close-are-you-to-an-epic-legendary-badge/32164#32164) if you use Greasemonkey).  Go to your profile reputation page (the one with the chart on it), View Source, and find the line that looks like this:

```
var d = [[1238832000000, 10],[1240300800000, 20], ...
```

Paste that, without the `var`, into the top of this Python script:

```
d = [[1238832000000, 10],[1240300800000, 20], ...
qualifying_days = 0
previous_rep = 0
for _, rep in d:
    if rep - previous_rep >= 200:
        qualifying_days += 1
    previous_rep = rep
print qualifying_days
```

That will print the number of days you hit 200 points.  (That probably isn't an exact match for how the badges are calculated, but it should be ballpark correct.)

Comment: I think I still got awhile before Troggy goes epic!

Comment: Voting to close. This references the old reputation profile page, and was obsoleted some time ago by the `/reputation` page anyhow.

Comment: Close voter gone insane: how on Earth can a discussion be closed as "can no longer be reproduced"? Sheesh.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JavaScript again, this time in [**easy-to-use Greasemonkey form**](http://www.shog9.com/greasemonkey/scripts/so_daily_rep_limit_badge_tracker.user.js):

[Voyeurism is fun http://shog9.com/so_fake_badge_tracker.png](http://shog9.com/so_fake_badge_tracker.png)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Daily rep limit badge tracker
// @namespace      http://shog9.com/greasemonkey/scripts
// @description    Tracks days a user has hit or exceeded the daily rep limit
// @include        https://stackoverflow.com/users/*
// @include        http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/users/*
// @include        http://superuser.com/users/*
// ==/UserScript==


var output = document.getElementById("date-selection");
if ( output )
   var rep_data = eval(document.getElementById("source")
      .innerHTML.toString().match( /\s+var d = (\[.*]]);/ )[1]);

if ( rep_data ) 
{   
   var capped_days = 0;
   for (var i=0; i < rep_data.length; ++i) 
   {
      var today = rep_data[i];
      var yesterday = rep_data[i-1] || [0,0];
      if (today[1] - 200 >= yesterday[1]) 
         ++capped_days;
   }

   output.innerHTML += "<div>Hit the reputation cap on " 
      + capped_days + " days: "
      + format_badge_distance(150, "Legendary", 1) + ", "
      + format_badge_distance(50, "Epic", 2) + ", "
      + format_badge_distance(1, "Mortarboard", 3)
      + "</div>";
}

function format_badge_distance(caps_needed, title, rank)
{
   if ( capped_days < caps_needed )
      return caps_needed - capped_days 
        + " more to achieve " 
        + format_badge(title, rank);
   else if ( capped_days > caps_needed )
      return capped_days - caps_needed 
        + " past " 
        + format_badge(title, rank);
   return " at " + format_badge(title, rank);
}

function format_badge(title, rank)
{
   return '<span class="badge"><span class="badge'
     + rank
     + '">&#9679;</span>&nbsp;'
     + title
     + '</span>';
}
```

And yes, I think we can safely say that this technique *doesn't work*: [Reed Copsey is placed at 148 days](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65358?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top), but holds the Legendary badge... Whatever SO uses internally, this isn't it.

Comment: Likewise, Darin Dimitrov and karim79 have the Epic badge, but they currently need to hit the rep cap another 1 and 6 times, respectively.

Comment: @Shog9, it's not working for me, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32687/so-greasemonkey-support-here-or-superuser

Comment: Interesting that the calculation for Epic and Legendary are *[still](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301720/do-i-have-17-50-200-rep-days-or-do-i-have-18)* not working.  How many "6-8 week" periods has it been since 2009?

Answer (score 11):

Bummer, this only lists me at 110, even though after playing with the query I used with [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32104/legendary-badge-calculation) some more I can show I've hit the cap closer to 180 times.  That means it's missing more than 1/3 of my hits.

Oh, and for those without a python interpreter handy, here's an html file you can paste your data into:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {

var d = [[1219737600000, 51],[1219824000000, 208],[1219910400000, 383],...];

var qualifying_days = 0;
var previous_rep = 0;
for (var i=0,il=d.length;i<il;i+=1) {
    if (d[i][1] - previous_rep >= 200) {
        qualifying_days += 1;
    }
    previous_rep = d[i][1];
}
document.getElementById('result').value = qualifying_days;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="result" /><button onclick="test()">GO</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That's more convenient than the Python or Perl versions. Apparently I'm at 208, which surprises me because I've been basically at the rep cap for 11 months or ~330 days. Now I haven't hit that 330 times I'm sure but I'm also sure I didn't "miss" 120 times, which supports your claim theres something wrong with the calculation.

Comment: cletus: does that include weekends?

Comment: I haven't factored weekends in but then again I haven't seen anywhere it's said only weekdays apply. Or did I miss something?

Comment: No, but 11 months of weekdays is fewer days than 11 full months - only ~240 days instead of ~335.

Comment: Weekends for me have a lower incidence of hitting the rep cap but it still happens sufficiently often to make me question the 208/330 number.

Answer (score 8):

Javascript version: http://jsbin.com/oyoka/edit

```
var d = [[1231660800000, 10],[1231747200000, 30],[1231833600000, 137]]; 

var counter = 0; 

for(i=1;i<d.length;i++) 
  if(d[i][1] - d[i-1][1] >= 200) 
    counter++; 

document.write(counter);
```

Only one day for me, btw.

Comment: +1 for a version that doesn't require me to install anything.

Answer (score 5):

Really, really far.

And that's assuming it's not in a row, the wording is really awkward.  It really ought to be "Hit the daily reputation cap X times (non-consecutive)" or something less ambiguous

Answer (score 4):

C version: (this is code golf, right? :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   char d[] = "[[1235289600000, 10],[1235462400000, 20], ...";

   char *word, *last;
   int loc, qualifying_days = 0, rep = 0, previous_rep = 0;

   word = strtok(d, ",");

   while (word)
   {   

      last = strchr(word, ']');

      if (last)
      {   
         loc = last - word;
         word[loc] = '\0';

         rep = atoi((word+1));

         if ((rep - previous_rep) >= 200)
         {   
            qualifying_days += 1;
         }

         previous_rep = rep;

      }

      word = strtok(NULL, ",");
   }

   printf("%d\n", qualifying_days);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: FAIL, _way_ too long of an entry for code golf, sorry. :-P

Answer (score 3):

Or:

```
print len([x for x in [d[i+1][1]-d[i][1] for i in range(len(d)-1)] if x >= 200])
```

**Update**: On further reflection, this is better:

```
print len([1 for i in range(len(d)-1) if d[i+1][1]-d[i][1] >= 200])
```

No need for those nested list comprehensions.

**Update again**: I just got my Legendary badge a few minutes ago. The above query currently returns 134 days on which I'd reached the rep cap, so the actual badge calculation is using a somewhat different formula.

Comment: I said Python, not Perl.  :-)

Comment: Functional Python is still Python!

Comment: Nah, Perl would be `print scalar grep { $_ >= 200 } map { $d[$_][-1] - $d[$_-1][-1] } (1..$#d);`

Comment: In spite of being an atheist, I thank god every time I see some Perl snippet for not having to learn that language.

Comment: @Amarghosh: Funny, I thought the same thing reading Greg's Python snippet.  To each his own, I guess.

Comment: @Adam Bellaire: Out of curiosity, do you feel the same reading the simple-syntax-only Python script in my question?

Comment: @RichieHindle: Actually, no, because that's how I expect Python to look.  But, with all respect to Greg, if you want terse, use Perl.  Right tool for the job and all of that.  The terse Python hurts my brain.

Comment: How about `print sum(200<=y[1]-x[1] for x,y in zip(d,d[1:]))`

Comment: @gnibbler: That's a bit evil to treat boolean values as integers. I wouldn't even count on that to work in all future Python versions.

Comment: @Greg: Oh you'll like Ruby then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Votes are anonymized, so it's impossible to deduct points for a user's downvotes.

I'm glad the data-dump XML is friendly!

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

die "Usage: $0 id-num\n" unless @ARGV == 1;
my $id = shift;
my %postid;
@postid{
  map { /\bId="([^"]+)"/ ? $1 : die "$0: missing Id:\n$_" }
  `grep -w 'OwnerUserId="$id"' posts.xml`
} = ();

my %repmod = (
  1 => +15,
  2 => +10,
  3 =>  -2,
);

my %increase;
open my $votes, "<", "votes.xml" or die "$0: open: $!";
while (<$votes>) {
  next unless /<row\b/;
  my %attr = /\b(CreationDate|VoteTypeId|PostId)="([^"]+)"/g;
  next unless exists $postid{ $attr{PostId} };
  $increase{ $attr{CreationDate} } += $repmod{ $attr{VoteTypeId} } || 0;
}

my $i = 0;
foreach my $date (sort keys %increase) {
  next unless $increase{$date} >= 200;
  printf "%4d. $date - $increase{$date}\n", ++$i;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$ cd Stack\ Overflow\ Data\ Dump\ -\ Feb\ 10/Content/022010\ SO
$ legend 22656
[...]
 475. 2010-01-25 - 865
 476. 2010-01-26 - 828
 477. 2010-01-27 - 1486
 478. 2010-01-28 - 1110
 479. 2010-01-29 - 1228
 480. 2010-01-30 - 418
 481. 2010-01-31 - 325
```