# Add number of days you hit the daily rep cap to your profile somewhere

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, daily-reputation-limit

If [How close are you to an Epic / Legendary badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32087/how-close-are-you-to-an-epic-legendary-badge) is to believed then it should be trivial to add that calculation to that page or a similar one somewhere.

Comment: a) I couldn't get that one to work, and b) Jeff/Joel never go for the "let's add a counter for feature X" ideas. Just saying.

Comment: I agree that they never go for the idea, but I still like the counter ideas -- both this and consecutive visited days ... I wish they would go for both!

Comment: Looks like a candidate for GreaseMonkey.

Comment: That would require using Firefox (rather than Chrome) for something other than debugging CSS or Javascript on a site I'm developing.

Answer (score 7):

This is available via the

`/reputation`

route.

Answer (score 1):

I think we should *focus first* on <strike>only report</strike> reporting statistics that are useful to someone other than oneself*. It doesn't add any value to show to the world that I have hit the rep cap an exact number of X times, as opposed to having earned a particular badge and not others.

The quality of my posts are not particularly measured in the number of times I have hit the cap -- that is more to do with how many quality answers I have written in one day.  My relative quality as a member of this community is more measured in my total score, the distribution of my posts over the range of scores, and the number of questions I ask to questions answered.

*<sub>Now I'm pondering whether I only don't care about this count because my own count is pathetically low -- under 5 if I recall. *grumble*</sub>

**PS:** On the other hand, **if we wanted to expose this count, the cleanest way I can think of doing it is to award Mortarboard more than once (but still limit Epic and Legendary to one-time deals).**

Comment: Except that a user can see a bunch of stats about himself already that noone else can see, like how much rep you've gained today, edits to your posts, # of answers/comments, badges received and so on. So this simply doesn't make sense. If you want to restrict it so no one else can see it, fine. But that's a different argument to not having it at all.

Comment: @cletus: fair enough. I've made previous posts asking for more statistics, even if only visible to oneself. I just don't see as much value in this one as others, e.g. mean and median value of all questions and answers or question:answer ratio.

Comment: Those questions can be answered from the data dump. This can't because of the anonymized voting data.

Answer (score 0):

This would be nice and I would love to see this.  However, I agree with John in the fact that if there is no counter in place for consecutive visted days, I don't think we will see one for the new epic/lengendary badges either.

However, the SO team always seems to surprise us some days, so maybe we will all have a merry chrismas really soon.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I would like this implemented, I think it would beat the surprise element of the badge and hence won't be implemented. If somebody is so keen about it, s?he can keep track of the number of days (her|him)self.

Comment: Well, I have the badges already so it doesn't matter to me per se. It doesn't even need to be public either so there's no EP aspect. Your argument is otherwise nonsensical. After all, you could technically keep track of people's phone numbers so what need is there for speed dial or contacts on a phone?

Comment: It's supposed to be a surprise when you get most badges - see Rob's comment to this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/so-badge-progress-report/3235#3235