# Add a way to see how many days you hit the cap (and 200 rep)

Tags: feature-request, badges, daily-reputation-limit, information-display

We used to be able to go to the reputation page, and see the complete calculation of reputation, and at the end of that it would show us how many days we hit the rep cap and how many days we hit 200 rep.  This was useful for us to see how close we were to the Epic and Legendary badges.

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation

While this page is still there and apparently calculating correctly, it no longer gives the correct amount of days you hit the reputation cap, it is no longer updating.  **Could we please get a display somewhere of that data?**

Here's a screenshot of the days for me on that page:

[image: Rep Cap For Me]

I already have the Epic badge (and got it when they changed the parameters for the rep cap and broke the reputation page), and have had quite a few rep cap and over 200 rep days since then.

I'm thinking that there is a good amount of space in the profile on the reputation tab where we could put that info:

[image: Rep Cap Possibility]

**EDIT:** OK, checking back after a few more rep cap & +200 days, and I see that the rep cap showed two more days, but the +200 didn't (and it should have).

Comment: I guess [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32093/add-number-of-days-you-hit-the-daily-rep-cap-to-your-profile-somewhere?rq=1) is now status-uncompleted.

Comment: Yeh, they broke it when they changed the rep cap parameters.

Comment: Calculates just fine here. Are you sure you're looking at the 3rd value (200 rep from every source) instead of the 2nd one (200 rep from upvotes only)? I've hit the cap 22 times, same as the overview page says.

Comment: Not disagreeing, but why do you say that `/reputation` is no longer  calcualted correctly.

Comment: Because my days shown are 47 and 42, and I already have the Epic badge (and got it when they changed parameters, so I'm way past that now).

Comment: That count has always been off (something about counting 200 rep vs counting capping vs counting non-cappable gains).

Comment: I just added a screenshot of what it's showing me.

Comment: The simple fact that you hit the rep cap more days than you hit 200 rep tells me that something is broken, because is seems impossible that you have had that many days where you had that many downvotes to drag you below 200 while still hitting the rep cap from upvotes.

Comment: @psubsee2003, it's a cryptic message, and has always been problematic, but at least it functioned somewhat.

Comment: @LanceRoberts from what I've seen, you have enough controversial posts to *maybe* result in numbers that are close, but it seems strange that you were rep capped via upvotes 5 more times than you hit 200, so you could be right something is a skew.  Although, my numbers from `/reputation` seem accurate.  I'm just too lazy to check them for certain.

Comment: @psubsee2003, those phrases they use don't mean what you think they mean (or what I think they mean).  There has always been a difference there with the top line larger than the bottom line.  I always thought of it as the bottom line being days I passed the rep cap, but I never knew if that was right or not.  It would take some research to figure it out.

Comment: Wait, so what statistic do you actually want here? Your example screenshot says rep cap, but that's not at all what the badge is based on. Those stats are probably pretty spot-on accurate, but while good indications of badge progress, are *not* completely accurate of your badge progress.

Comment: @animuson, well that's a valid point, since nothing is tied to rep cap anymore(?) I suppose I'd be fine with how many days I hit 200, but either way would be close enough.  Even with their change in parameters it's hard to know the system precisely, it would make a good post for someone on the Team if they could lay it all out.

Comment: @animuson, ok, I edited it to reflect both stats.

Comment: @LanceRoberts about your edit, you may have hit the rep cap in the preceeding 2 days, but because of the bounties you started, you never hit 200 rep

Comment: @psubsee2003, it's possible that's how it's calculating that, but don't think that that is what matters for the badge.  It'd be interesting if someone in the know could chime in on the exact formula.

Comment: @psubsee2003, remember I already have the Epic badge, and it's showing me 42.

Comment: @LanceRoberts there still may be an issue, but I was trying pointing out that the field on the page says "earned at least 200 reputation on X days", nothing more.  So it probably only reflects how many days the rep counter says 200.  You did hit the rep cap from upvotes only both days and that field incremented, but you technically failed to hit 200 and it didn't increment.  Given that, there is probably no field on that page that is the equivilant of "Number of days that contribute to the Epic badge"

Comment: @LanceRoberts and yes, I do realize that was the purpose of this feature request

Comment: So is there any consensus on how the values in those 2 fields relate to the progress towards the legendary badge? I'm confused...

Comment: @Szymon, it's hard to be sure right now, I left a message for Nick Craver hoping he would chime in.

Comment: See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332398/rep-cap-reached-but-not-counted-towards-legendary-badge/332407#comment1084489_332398 and   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332398/rep-cap-reached-but-not-counted-towards-legendary-badge/332407#comment1084489_332398

Comment: If and admin feels this has been fixed by badge status reports, then it should be tagged as 'status-completed'.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative whilst this is not implemented, you can use the '**[Stinking Badges!](http://agent86ix.github.io/stackapps/badge)**' web app to track your progress towards the legendary (therefore epic), generalist and nice/good/great question/answer badges.

Comment: Looks cool, but it didn't show me any progress towards Legendary and I'm over a third of the way there.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Oh, not for me either.  Hmm possibly a temporary issue as was working as recently as last week? Sorry about that!

Comment: It would help if that page showed when it was last updated. Rules change over time, or criteria previously unknown comes up. For example, does that script exclude downvotes, which are not calculated into the totals for these badges?

Comment: @animuson why not look through the code yourself? After all, this is Stack Overflow (Meta)

Comment: @ColeJohnson What code?

Comment: @hichris123 The code of that web app. It is GitHub...

Comment: Yeah exactly, this is Stack Overflow. If I wanted to look through the code myself, I'd be on Unix and Linux instead.