# Rep cap reached but not counted towards Legendary badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

Yesterday, I rep-capped on Meta Stack Exchange, but this instance wasn't counted towards the Legendary badge. [Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20190816063738/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=topactivity) is the situation on August 16th, three days ago, with the counter on 112, and [this morning it's still 112](http://web.archive.org/web/20190819062735/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=topactivity). I received one unaccept yesterday, which is *probably* the reason why it didn't count; according to the [FAQ](/a/188731),

> Unupvotes and unaccepts affect the day the undo event occurred.

However, I also undownvoted a few answers and the total on my profile page is still 200, even taking the -15 into account.

[image]

Here's a dump of my /reputation page:

```
 2    332344 (10)
 2    332344 (10)
 2    332344 (10)
 2    332344 (10)
-- 2019-08-17 rep +40   = 77012     
 2    332251 (10)
 2    332369 (10)
 2    332369 (10)
 2    332369 (10)
 2    332372 (5)
 2    332369 (10)
 2    332369 (10)
 3    332369 (-2)
 2    332369 (10)
 2    332372 (5)
 2    332369 (10)
 2    332369 (10)
 2    332369 (10)
 2    332372 (5)
 2    332369 (10)
 2    332372 (5)
 2    332369 (10)
 2    332369 (10)
 2    332247 (5)
 2    332369 (10)
 2    332251 (10)
 2    332369 (10)
 2    332372 (5)
 2    332344 (10)
 1    332233 (2)
 1    332052 (2)
 1    330391 (2)
 1    313793 (2)
 1    313792 (2)
 1    298279 (2)
 2    332369 [2]
-- 2019-08-18 rep +212  = 77224     
 2    332369 (10)
-- 2019-08-19 rep +10   = 77234
```

Comment: If that is true, the FAQ must be adjusted. But the accept/unaccept was on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332344/295232); the accept happened on a day I didn't rep cap. I'm also pretty sure that I didn't see a decrease in the counter.

Comment: @Secespitus That was discovered to be untrue a while ago due to a huge rewrite of the badge code that a lot of people weren't aware changed so much. The bug on your meta is from a different aspect of the system where it doesn't keep rechecking the user's reputation cap throughout the day once they've already hit it - further reputation gains are only corrected by a recalc.

Comment: [Legendary Maxwell](https://youtu.be/sBlhrTpi69E).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As indicated by the FAQ, only unupvotes and unaccepts affect the day they occurred. Because downvotes are not considered in any way for those badges, undownvotes are also ignored for it.

Calculating all the events for that day minus the downvote and undownvoted events, that day calculates out to 199 for you.

Comment: OK, that makes sense ... sort of. I couldn't really gain more reputation that day, except by accepting more answers. The ` 2    332369 [2]` line shows the last answer upvote only counted for +2, not +10 because of the reputation cap.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yeah, the way this is done makes no sense at all to me honestly. And it's highly prone to abuse because it no longer excludes serial voting and stuff that we were sure was prevented for a long time. It makes the badges kind of luck based in my opinion but well, that's the way it's currently designed to work for performance reasons.

Comment: Yeah, no hard feelings, thanks for the explanation. I guess we'll just need to live with how it's currently built, until it is changed. Time for a [status-bylackofdesign]?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me why reputation earned from removing downvotes counts toward the reputation cap. I thought removing a vote was supposed to count as if the vote had never existed. Is it to prevent exceeding the cap by removing a whole bunch of old downvotes?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog They don't. What gave you the idea that they do?