# Epic / Legendary badges: counting the days

Tags: feature-request, bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Legendary Badge calculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32104/legendary-badge-calculation)

Related: [Observation about downvotes and epic/legendary badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35350/observation-about-downvotes-and-epic-legendary-badge)

I'm using [this greasemonkey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32087/how-close-are-you-to-an-epic-legendary-badge) script and today it's showing that I've reached the daily reputation limit on 51 days. But the `Epic` badge wasn't coming, and since I'm a relatively new user, I created a little manual statistics for the days I have => 200, and for the days that I have near 200.

The days with => 200 turned out to be **38**.

And the number of days when I've actually reached the daily reputation limit (as the badge says) is **55**.

Now, since on many of those days I have upvotes that are ignored due to *then* reaching the reputation limit, it seems a bit "unfair" to have such a big margin. The discrepancy, of course is due to:

- my downvotes
- deleted questions
- users undoing accepted answers

So here's my suggestion: In order to have more proper results - i.e. at least to meet the badge description, make it work as follows:

- count all days with `reputation => 200`
- count all days where you have upvotes whose reputation was "trimmed" (due to the rep cap)
- (optional) count all days where `reputation + own downvotes => 200`

P.S. No, I'm not complaining that "mommy, I didn't get my badgey. * weep * ". I'm suggestion a rational improvement.

P.S.S. I'm tagging "bug", because it might be realized as such. Imagine what the discrepancy will for for the Legendary badge - it might be 50!