# Possible bug in legendary badge calculation

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, daily-reputation-badges

<sup>I originally posted this in [another topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32104/legendary-badge-calculation), but then I realized that this is a better fit in a real Question (I always comment to SO newbs *"Please do not post Questions as Answers :)"*, it would be arrogant not to do the same ;) ).</sup>

I noticed that [Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers) became [Legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary) today. I first wondered because he has a relatively low reputation to earn the badge (as opposed to others when they received it), so I went to his [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61974?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) with the well known [Greasemonkey thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32087/how-close-are-you-to-an-epic-legendary-badge/32164#32164) turned on and the script tells that he has yet 14 days left for the badge.

True, I know that the script isn't perfect, it's often being optimistic with 2~3 days *ahead*, but 14 days as in this case is a pretty huge gap and it's even a gap *behind*.

Bug?

<sub>Nothing against Mark btw. I don't even know him.</sub>

Comment: Uf, it hurts to hear "low reputation" in reference to 43k, even if relative.

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit: actually, you're right.

The recent [global rep recalc](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/) affected this badge, because it "unlocked" reputation above the cap for accepted answers.

> - accepted answers and bounties were only *partially* immune to the rep cap before depending on the time of day you earned them, but they are *fully* immune now.
> - upvotes can now “replace” missing rep lost to downvotes, up to the +200 daily reputation cap.

So, then:

1. Should we allow the badge's behavior to be changed, with newer slightly relaxed rules?
2. Should we revert it to the "original" behavior?

I am looking at this now and **I am inclined to leave it the way it is (and update the badge description if necessary)**. If we limit it to rep-cap through *upvotes only* it becomes extraordinarily strict. For example right now there are *zero* users on SU or SF who have achieved this, and only I have achieved it on meta (and I don't really count).

The users who have earned Legendary (including yourself!) REALLY earned it my opinion. Making it even more strict seems.. cruel.

Comment: hey Jeff, I have written rep-cap counter based on /reputation [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49149), If you don't mind, could you test my greasemonkey script on Mark Byers's page, and let me know his rep-cap total days? I just want to verify my logic of calculation is correct or not.

Comment: excellent the script works! thanks @S.Mark (I'll add this calc to the server-side code later tomorrow so everyone can see the results)

Comment: Wow, Thats great, Really thank you, @Jeff. Cheers!

Comment: I would revert it to the original behaviour, because that's where the reputation cap stands for and the badge was originally designed for 150 real rep-cap hits. The script of @S.Mark does it indeed right. It sums up the reputation earned by votes only. If that removes "too much" already-awarded Legendary badges, then you could maybe lower the limit to 125 rep-cap hits or so.

Comment: True, they really earned it :) How about to lower the rep-cap hits to 125 or even 100? Do we still get the same users? And in line with this, that would mean that the Epic and Mortarboard badges also needs to be changed/recalculated/redescribed.

Comment: I wish someone would create more badges the people can get.

Comment: @BalusC, If it is too strict, Personally, I prefer changing days count on Badges, for example, Epic to 40 days and Legendary to 120 days, instead of changing rep-cap to 125 or 100. because changing rep-cap can confuse the real meaning rep-capping.

Comment: @S.Mark: with "rep-cap hits" I *actually* meant the amount of days it was hitted :) I didn't mean the rep-cap itself.

Comment: Can anyone clarify what the bottom 2 values on the rep report now are?  I have `rep cap was reached on 79 days` and `rep cap was exceeded on 105 days`, the wording at least is confusing, as you have to reach it to exceed it...or am I missing something else?

Comment: @Nick: `reached` stands for >=200 rep earned by pure votes. `exceeded`  stands for >=200 rep earned by votes AND accepted answers. Confusing wording indeed if you don't know the logic behind it.

Comment: @BalusC - thanks, now those numbers make a lot more sense :)

Comment: I'm now for several (i believe at least 2 weeks) at "rep cap exceeded for 150 days" but haven't seen legendary yet. Is there something wrong going on in calculation? Or does it only gimme the badge if i reach 151? (did so yesterday).