# Shouldn't I have received the Legendary badge by now?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges, daily-reputation-badges

In my particular scenario, the reputation audit says

```
rep cap was exceeded on 152 days
```

[Shog9's GreaseMonkey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32087/how-close-are-you-to-an-epic-legendary-badge/32164#32164) says I'm at 148, but it's been documented that there are many discrepancies and inconsistencies in how `{Epic}` and `{Legendary}` are calculated.

Regardless, I reached 150 a couple of days ago and I waited the extra few days (as these badges aren't calculated daily, we're told), but I've still yet to receive my `{Legendary}`.

This was also [the case with VonC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge) which got up to 154 (and more) before receiving the badge. Others have been in much worse situations based on anecdotal evidence, with some still waiting for the badge after months of delay, perhaps with no clear explanation.

For the benefit of all, I'd like the `{Epic}` and `{Legendary}` badges rules to be further *clarified and enforced*, but in my localized case, I'd like to know what else do I need to do to get my `{Legendary}` badge. Because I will do them.

Comment: It shows me at 167 days now and I still don't have mine :(

Comment: @Joel: I feel your pain, though obviously in much lesser degree. StackOverflow encourages competition, but this is just straight up unfair. Broken, even.

Comment: I just bountied VonC's question. For the second time. Feel free to close this question as a dupe, make it vanish like Joel's or whatever. Just provide quality authoritative answer to the question, please. Isn't that what we're all about?

Comment: @poly I agree that it seems broken, but you sound almost hysterical; your comments make it seem like you're about 10 seconds away from driving to California and knocking on Jeff's door demanding badges. I'm sure you'll get it; nobody will deny you your rightful Legendary status

Comment: Actually, I got mine at 161 rep "cap exceeded" and 96 "cap reached". I still have no idea why that particular score triggered that badge. Btw, congrats in advanced for your Legendary badge! You got it in 6 months! It only took me 22 months... ;)

Comment: @Joel you got it! (And you, too, Poly :)

Comment: @Jarrod: Thank you, thank you, thank you. You don't know how much this means to me.

Comment: @Jarrod - awesome, you rock!

Comment: @VonC: well isn't that obvious? 96=6*16, 161, the numbers are symmetric, 161 can be factored as (1+6)*(16+1+6)... The numbers just added up, the time was right!

Comment: @sehe: I had forgotten about that question! I am now at 226 (upvotes *only*) and 373 (at least 200 rep). Can I have another badge?

Comment: @VonC: Aw, you just missed the mark for 7*37 vs. 373... I would aim for 329=7*47 vs. 474 (having the added bonus of 7*47 being the prime factors). However, these targets are tough to miss and it will take you at least till 2012-02-04 ... (but that will give you some more time to request the new badge for the occasion :))

Comment: @sehe: darn it! 331 and 463. I missed your mark... On the plus side, it didn't took me as long as you said. Of course, this helped (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/), and restored some rep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an issue with how the badge is calculated - it uses the `TargetRepChange` field on the votes table to aggregate the total rep gained for a day.

`TargetRepChange` is a denormalized representation of how much an individual vote is worth to receiving user.  For example, an up vote on an answer could record `10` in the field.  If the receiving user had reached the rep cap for the day, `0` would be recorded.

Things can get messy when a user's posts are deleted - because `TargetRepChange` is set when the vote is cast, a deletion on a future day could cause the rep cap to no longer be reached, even if there were more votes garnered.

Your [/reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation) report **does not** use this field when summing rep for a day - we rerun all the logic for an accurate report, using the most current ruleset.

**So we can fix the data**.  We haven't done a lot of it yet, because it's a very expensive operation: almost 10 million votes and all the accompanying logic behind them have to be run for a global fix.

But for an individual user, I'm adding integrated adjustment of `TargetRepChange` when a moderator recalcs a user's rep.  I think in the future, we're going to allow users to recalc their own reputation (time-limited, of course :), so you'll be able to help sort out issues on your own.

Comment: So I do still have more days to go or do I actually deserve it already but the bug makes it not so? What do I have to do to get this before September?

Comment: I'll be working on this tonight and tomorrow, so hopefully you'll get your badge this weekend.  Cash would speed this process considerably - how much is your Legendary worth to you? :)

Comment: with all that VC money, why not just have one of your servants do it for you? :-D

Answer (score 2):

I've posted a similar question before: [Possible bug in legendary badge calculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49147/possible-bug-in-legendary-badge-calculation). Jeff marked it `Status-Completed` at 17 august without notification. Further,  the last one who earned the badge on Stackoverflow was [Oded](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded). He earned it *before* 14 august.

Probably Jeff actually changed something at 17 august which caused the legendary badge rewarder to behave differently or to be completely broken.

Jeff is the only one who can reasonably investigate and answer this.

Comment: Jeff did change something, I believe in response to this premature `{Epic}` http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61091/why-did-i-get-the-epic-badge ; the fix is alluded to in a comment http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge/58192#58192 ; previously, deleted posts still counted toward the badges, but this was then (supposedly) fixed.