# Legendary badge awarded too early - or /reputation is wrong

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Epic badge received too early?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85363/epic-badge-received-too-early)

Not complaining, but today I received the Legendary badge, even though /reputation shows I still have 8 days before I should have earned it:

[image]

Clearly there is math somewhere that has determined I actually earned 200 rep on 150 days, so perhaps the missing 8 were due to things like bounties, removed users, voting reversals, migrations, etc. and are not reflected above even though those days did count toward the badge. But it would be good to have something documented somewhere that explains why these numbers might be off in either direction.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85363/epic-badge-received-too-early) (still unanswered) points to these two questions, where allegedly there was some type of answer, but those questions have been removed:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52800/slightly-premature-legendary-badge

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge

Comment: The tally may not record days where users/posts were deleted. Just guessing though. Would need to look at the SQL and code to be sure.

Comment: @Oded yeah, I suppose this overlaps with [the question about the Epic badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85363/epic-badge-received-too-early), since the answer is likely the same. But it hasn't been answered yet either...

Comment: Same happened to me, a while back. Got awarded before I should have. Someone complained. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62480/shouldnt-i-have-received-the-legendary-badge-by-now/62561#62561

Comment: I added my answer to the dupe you linked, Aaron.