# Bug in calculation of "rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only*"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, daily-reputation-limit

Here is what I have in the end of https://stackoverflow.com/reputation:

```
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 11 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 11 days
```

Checking my reputation tab I only see 19 upvotes for today:

[image]

Since both `rep cap via upvotes` and `at least 200 rep` messages are 11 days, it means that both of them are for the same set of days. Otherwise `at least 200 rep` would be higher:

`"earned at least 200 rep" days` == `"rep cap via upvotes only" days` + `other days I've reached 200 cap, but not via upvotes`

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding the meaning of those messages in https://stackoverflow.com/reputation?

Update: 
I just received my 20th upvote and the both counts on https://stackoverflow.com/reputation remain 11.

Comment: I'm confused, are you suggesting that the screen shoted day; hit the rep cap but shouldn't have?

Comment: The screenshot say I have 19 upvotes today, but the `reputation` link says that I have reached the cap.

Comment: How can you be certain today is one of the 11 days?

Comment: `earned at least 200` - 11 days
`rep cap via upvotes` - also 11 days -> therefore, on all the days I earned 200 rep, I also reached rep cap via upvotes, otherwise by `earned at least 200` would be higher than `rep cap via upvotes`. Plus, just a few minutes ago the `rep cap via upvotes` was 10

Comment: Actually this is interesting, you have in your profile **exactly 11 days** when you have more than 200 points and in most of those you **didn't actually hit the rep cap** http://stackoverflow.com/users/2454376/mishik?tab=reputation&sort=graph

Comment: For example july the 4th where you recieved 217 but also had 3 (net) accepts

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes, I've noticed this few days ago, but wanted to prepare some proof before asking the question :)

Comment: Don't forget that if a post is deleted over 60 days _after_ you gained reputation for it, that reputation will not be removed, though the post will no longer appear in your reputation audit page.

Comment: @Oded he has only been a member of SO for 36 days.

Comment: @RalZarek - Missed that. Will need to take another look.

Comment: A potentially related observation: I received my Epic and Legendary badges on SO several days before I should have (at least according to that "n days" message on the /reputation page), and the same thing happened on dba.SE. I [complained about the Legendary badge here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165627/legendary-badge-awarded-too-early-or-reputation-is-wrong) and then found that there are [some discrepancy explanations in the answers here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85363/epic-badge-received-too-early).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We suck at counting, what can I say?

The next build will properly filter down to *just* upvotes on this tally.