# Legendary Badge Description needs updated: "Earned at least 200 reputation on 150 days"

Tags: feature-request

This may indeed be the most earth shattering problem with Stackoverflow. I don't think I need to point out that this is **big deal**, but I just did.

The Legendary Badge's FAQ description is difficult to interpret.

I propose "Earned at least 200 reputation on each of 150 individual days"

This ought to remove the confusion regarding "on 150 days" as in "on half a year????"

It should also remove the confusion regarding "is it consecutive days or not?"

Good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This interpretation of the Legendary badge is exactly what my interpretation was, until I read [Legendary badge calculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32104/legendary-badge-calculation), which explained that the badge is earned when you've hit the daily reputation cap 150 times.

Until I read that, I planned on pulling an all-nighter on my 150th day to stay up and answer as many questions as I could in anticipation of hitting the reputation cap.

In short, it probably would  be a good idea to update the badge description.  I support this feature-request.