# Where do you see daily reputation earned and when cap is hit?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I see a lot of users on meta referring to their daily reputation but I don't see those stats in my profile.  I can see the rep graph which shows it climbing, but posts here are referring to very specific numbers, not estimates from a graph.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32087/how-close-are-you-to-an-epic-legendary-badge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the envelope icon to the left of your name.

Then click the "Reputation" tab.

Comment: I never realized the envelope was a different link from the name.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Jon Skeet's Rep Tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/stackoverflow/reputationtracker.aspx)