# Do I have 17/50 +200 rep days, or do I have 18?

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, daily-reputation-badges

I'm an active community member at [dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10832/max-vernon) where I am currently working towards the Epic badge.

On August 30th, 2017, I had enough upvotes for well over +200 rep (42 upvotes, plus a couple "accepts").  However, since someone un-upvoted one of my posts, the rep-calculator shown in the site banner claimed I only had [+196 for the day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71icH.png).

My rep for the day, taken from /reputation on [dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/reputation):

```
-- 2017-08-30 rep +260  = 36789     
 3    184756 (-2)
 2    184622 (10)
 3    184756 (-2)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184756 (5)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2     40062 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184806 (10)
 2    184805 (5)
 2    184805 (5)
 2    184805 (5)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184806 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184806 (10)
 2    184805 (5)
 2    184805 (5)
 2    184806 [4]
 2    184622 [0]
 2    184806 [0]
 2    184622 [0]
 2    184793 [0]
 2    184622 [0]
 2    184806 [0]
 2    184805 [0]
 2    184832 [0]
 2    184832 [0]
 2    184622 [0]
 2    184622 [0]
 2    184622 [0]
 2    184805 [0]
 2    184806 [0]
 2    184622 [0]
 2    184622 [0]
 2    184622 [0]
 2    184756 [0]
```

The summary from /reputation shows:

```
days represented 1169
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 14 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 18 days
```

According to the above summary, I should have 18 of the 50 days required for Epic, however my profile shows progress towards the Epic badge as 17 out of 50:

[image]

It seems like there is a bug counting +200 days when an un-upvote occurs that same day.  This seems like a bug that should be fixed if you care about high-rep users; why would I try for +200 days, if all it takes is a single un-upvote to ruin the entire day's effort?

I realize there are numerous questions here about rep-cap, including [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308548/426671), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56620/does-acquiring-only-200-reps-in-a-day-from-only-votes-count-toward-epic-legendar), etc, etc...

FYI, this is related to [How does rep calc work when nearing the 200 daily rep cap?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2827/how-does-rep-calc-work-when-nearing-the-200-daily-rep-cap)

Comment: I suspect its by design. It checks at the end of the day or something, and I've had that happen to me once. Kinda sucks, but there's probably good reasons for it.

Comment: If it's by design, the design sucks (that's the technical term).

Answer (score 2):

The reputation change is calculated in the order the events happen.

So you get 20 up votes for 200 reputation.

The next upvote is "lost" as you've hit the cap.

If you get a down-vote that takes you to 198.

If you get another up-vote you'll get +2 from it to take you back to 200.

If you get an up-vote that's a -10 so the "realtime" reputation indicator takes 10 off what it thinks is your total which may well then report less than 200 as it doesn't add the reputation from a previously "lost" vote.

When the reputation for the day is recalculated at the end of the day it will recognise that a previously "lost" vote can now be used (fully or in part) and will award you the reputation for that. This means that the badge progress indicator which uses the "realtime" calculations can be out.

It should "catch-up" within a couple of days. If it hasn't then you might need the intervention of an employee to force a recalculation of the progress. The fact that the reputation page says "18 days" would indicate that the system knows you should be at 18/50.

This is very much by design.

Comment: Except that didn't happen.  I ended the day at 196.

Comment: @MaxVernon I suspect that the reputation indicator on the top bar isn't 100% accurate. If you look in your reputation history you'll see that you did get 200+ for that day - the "[4]" indicates that you got partial reputation from an event to take you back to the cap.

Comment: So, why didnt the progress towards Epic increment?

Comment: @MaxVernon that I don't know. Did the Epic counter update the next day? I would expect it to be conservative when it does update. The reputation summary says "18 days", and I'd believe that over the badge progress indicators.

Comment: The badge indicator *still* shows 17/50

Comment: @MaxVernon - I'm out of ideas then. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for trying, anyway!

Comment: @Max Progress indicator might be "stuck", hopefully when you will earn 200 again it will re-calculate and show 20.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I've since had many +200 days, and *still* the count on my profile page is incorrect vs the /reputation page.